# The Octahedral Axiom in group theory

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, triangulated-categories

$\require{AMScd}$Here are two results about groups:

(**The third isomorphism theorem**) Suppose that I have $A \triangleleft B \triangleleft C$ and $A \triangleleft C$. Then $C/B \cong (C/A)/(B/A)$.

(**An exercise I just assigned my students**) Suppose that we have $X \triangleleft Z$ and $Y \triangleleft Z$ with $X \cap Y = 1$. Then $(Z/X)/Y \cong (Z/Y)/X$.

> **Vague question a student just asked me**: Is there some general context in which to think of these results and why they look similar?

We can write these as diagrams with exact rows and columns:
\begin{gather}
\begin{CD}
@. @. 1 @. 1 \\
@. @. @VVV @VVV \\
1 @>>> A @>>> B @>>> B/A @>>> 1 \\
@. @| @VVV @VVV \\
1 @>>> A @>>> C @>>> C/A @>>> 1 \\
@. @. @VVV @VVV \\
@. @. C/B @>\cong>> (C/A)/(B/A) \\
@. @. @VVV @VVV \\
@. @. 1 @. 1
\end{CD} \\
\begin{CD}
@. @. 1 @. 1 \\
@. @. @VVV @VVV \\
@. @. X @= X \\
@. @. @VVV @VVV \\
1 @>>> Y @>>> Z @>>> Z/Y @>>> 1 \\
@. @| @VVV @VVV \\
1 @>>> Y @>>> Z/X @>>> (Z/X)/Y \cong (Z/Y)/X @>>> 1 \\
@. @. @VVV @VVV \\
@. @. 1 @. 1
\end{CD}
\end{gather}
If we were in an abelian category, these would be two forms of the octahedral axiom.

> **Vague but more technical question**: Is there something like a [semi-abelian category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semi-abelian+category) which includes the case of groups, and where we have something like an octahedral axiom?

Comment: I guess this looks a lot like the $3 \times 3$ lemma, and maybe that is the answer, but that usually comes with an assumption that the diagram commutes and deduces exactness, whereas here I have a bunch of exact sequences and the theorem is that there is an isomorphism making the diagram commute.

Comment: On thinking about this more, the right answer to the student's question is probably the $3 \times 3$ diagram built from a group $G$ and two normal subgroups $N_1$ and $N_2$, whose entries are $N_1 \cap N_2$, $N_1$, $N_1 N_2/N_2$, $N_2$, $G$, $G/N_2$, $N_1 N_2/N_1$, $G/N_2$ and $G/(N_1 N_2)$, and I was distracted by the octahderon. But I'll leave this up and see what someone else has to say.

Comment: This resemblance is because the octahedral axiom is a shadow of the exact same theorem in a stable ∞-category, where you replace cokernels by homotopy cofibres. See Theorem 1.1.2.14 of Jacob Lurie's Higher Algebra for a proof that the octahedral axiom arises naturally in this way

Comment: @Harry Gindi In what stable oo-category would a general (nonabelian) group be an object?

Comment: @DanPetersen None of them, but analyzing the proof of TR4 from stability, it seems like you can get away with a bit less.

Comment: @LSpice Sure, go ahead.

Comment: David, doesn't the exercise you assigned only looks like the third isomorphism theorem because (a) **it fundamentally uses it**, and (b) you used the lattice isomorphism theorem to write it in a "slicker" (but technically incorrect) manner.  What I mean is that $X$ is not a subgroup of $Z/Y$ so $(Z/Y)/X$ literally makes no sense.  Making things technical, you are claiming $(Z/Y)/(XY/Y) \cong (Z/X)(XY/X)$, which is a simple consequence of (two applications of) the 3rd isomorphism theorem.  [Of course, you are correct that $XY/Y\cong X$ when $X\cap Y=1$, etc...]

Comment: Is there an easy way to separate the two diagrams a bit more? As currently shown, it's a bit difficult to keep track of what's going where.

Comment: @user44191, [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352463/the-octahedral-axiom-in-group-theory#comment883854_352463)'s my fault; I edited to convert to AMScd, but didn't separate them enough.  I won't edit again because I don't know what triggers CW status, but probably just putting them in two separate environments rather than in one big `{gather}` as I did would be enough.